# I am writing data of turtlebot movement, and I want to write a paper. How can I get the data?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, rosbag, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I am a ROS beginner. I am doing SLAM of turtlebot 2 in the ubuntu 14.04, ros (indigo) personal computer environment.

I need the following data to write a paper.
How can I get the data?
(In navigation, I want data from RViz where I specified the goal point myself)

1. The global map and the trajectory that the robot actually moved in the global map
2. Movement distance and travel time from the start point to the goal point
3. Data for making graphs of speed and distance, speed and time

that's all.
What should I do?rosbag?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312257/i-am-writing-data-of-turtlebot-movement,-and-i-want-to-write-a-paper.-how-can-i-get-the-data?/) by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2019-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should record a `rosbag` of all your runs so that you can playback your data whenever you want, even if you can't use your robot. Plus, this has the added benefit of recording your trajectories and setpoints that you send to your robot as well. Then you can focus on visualizing and analyzing your data without any pressure of getting it right while doing an experiment.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2019-01-09**:
thank you!!I want to use rosbag to make robot destinations every time. However, it does not work if you record and play it with this. why?`rosbag record /move_base_simple/goal`

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
Try

```
rosbag record -O subset /move_base_simple/goal
```

to record only a subset of topics and see the [rosbag tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials)

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2019-01-09**:
You can certainly record. Looking at `rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal` during playback. The topic has been submitted. However, the robot does not move.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
I don't understand what you mean. Did the data get recorded?

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2019-01-09**:
yes!and publish.however, turtlebot dont move.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
Ok, well that problem can't be answered without more information which would be out of scope for this question. You should create a new question for the new problem.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
If this answered your question about recording the data, then can you please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark (✅)?

**Comment by [saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/37890/saito/) on 2019-01-09**:
yea!!thanks!!